# Jenkins commit a file after successful build

Tags: file, ant, jenkins, checkin, post-commit

I am using Jenkins, Ant , Flex and Java for my web application.
Currently I update a build version file in Flex src and commit it before starting Jenkins build. 
I want to avoid this manual process and let script do this for me.

Contents of file:

Build=01_01_2013_10:43
Release=2.01

**Question1:**
I want to update this file contents and compile my code and then commit this file back to svn. So that SVN has latest build version number.

How do I commit this changed file to SVN. Would be great if commit happens after successful build.

**Question2:** I want to send an email to all developers an hour before build starts. "Please commit your changes. Build will start in 1 hr." Can I set up a delay between email and (actual svn export + ant build).
                             or 
Do I have to schedule 2 jobs an hour apart. One to send email and one to do build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [subclipse svn ant integration](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html) to commit changed files to SVN including authentication:

```
<svnSetting
      svnkit="true"
      username="bingo"
      password="bongo"
      id="svn.settings"
  />
<svn refid="svn.settings">
    <commit file="your.file" />
</svn>
```

To get username and password to the build file you have different options. One would be to use a [parametrized build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), where you define user name and password as build parameters which can be evaluated in the build file.

```
      username="${parameter.svn.username}"
      password="${parameter.svn.password}"
```

A second option is using a the [jenkins config file provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin). With this you can also use the parameters like for the parametrized build, but you import the credentials from the provided config file, e.g. a properties file can be imported via

```
<property file="config.file" />
```

Actually you can also use [ant's exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to execute your subversion commit the file.

For sending an e-mail one hour before actually building, you should setup two jobs, which are scheduled one hour apart. But I don't think this is good practice to notify before building, consider to build more often maybe even per commit to svn.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. We are currently not planning for CI. Our Flex project build takes nearly 15 minutes and most of changes are simple UI changes. We are currently doing a scheduled build per day.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept the answer if it is valid for you.

Comment: How do I get username and password to the svn. I know jenkins stores these credentials per job. How do I pass these credentials to build file.

Comment: This means I must have username and password in build file. I need a way to pass username and password from Jenkins to build file and not hardcode in build file. The same svn credentials which I give during jenkins project should be passed over to build file as parameters.

Comment: Jenkins polls "repo_a" for changes and builds it whenever change occurs, the build process commits back to "repo_a" (if build was successful) by updating a version file.. Wouldn't this create an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Post build Task plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) to execute svn as a shell script (svn must be installed and authenticated from the shell once for the user that runs Jenkins).

Then the svn commit runs as a post build action. The plugin has an option (checkbox) to run the script only if the previous build/steps were successful.

The plugins is also mentioned here: [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins)