# How to set the build result when executing on the slave

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have established under what conditions Jenkins Groovy plugins will execute on either the master or the slave.  Ultimately, I want to execute in the context of the current build on the slave.  However, since you only have access to the API available in slave.jar, I am now stuck with how to set or change the result of the current build.  Based on whether a built file is zero in size or not, should influence whether the build is marked as unstable.  So, running on the slave, I have access to the file through:

```
new File("/path/to/built/file/on/the/slave")
```

I can check its size and decide whether the build should be marked as unstable.  However, without the API access to hudson.model.Executor, how do you then accomplish this?  The typical groovy `manager` API is not available through the plugin I am using either, so you must use native APIs.

Alternatively, is there a way to set the build to unstable instead of failed, from a shell script?  It's a shame none of the shell script plugins provide an exit code evaluation property to allow you to control the build state based on this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You probably have already but if not have alook at this question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins