# In jenkins, execute shell command based on test result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to execute a shell command using

```
jenkins
```

based on test result. that means,

```
if the test result is successfull, i will execute the shell script and if not, i quit.
```

which plugin i have to use???

please save my searching time by giving ur suggestion.

Comment: When you are talking about tests, is it unitary tests? Or functional tests? You are executing your tests in a Jenkins job after the build? It's just to understand how can I help :)

Comment: solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins

Comment: Yep using a post shell task is the solution :)