# JIRA issue on jenkins job failure

Tags: jenkins, jira

I want to integrate Jenkins with jira so that, as soon as a build fails an issue is created in jira. I have already tried jira create issue in jenkins but its not creating any issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins)

The accepted answer by @Daniel Magnussen refers to http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task  This is what you need as well

When the build fails, just send a curl request to jira's rest api to create a new issue. Here is some info on how to create the issue with curl:

https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue

Comment: What does the "Create JIRA issue do then?" Can't we use this post build action to directly create the issue? instead of running the script?