# How to execute shell as post-build action?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins CI and I would like to add some post-build actions.

I've tried to follow suggestions from [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11160363/55075) post, but I cannot find such option (*Post build task*) which should allow me to execute shell commands. I can select *Execute shell*, but only for *Build*.

Here are my all options:

[image: Jenkins - Add post-build action]

Transcript:

> Add post-build action:
>
> - Aggregate downstream test results
> - Archive the artifacts
> - Build other projects
> - Console output (build log) parsing
> - GitHub PR: add labels
> - GitHub PR: close PR
> - GitHub PR: post comment
> - GitHub PR: remove labels
> - GitHub PR: set PR status
> - Publish HTML reports
> - Publish JUnit test result report
> - Publish Javadoc
> - Record fingerprints of files to track usage
> - Use publishers from another project
> - Git Publisher
> - Build other projects (manual step)
> - E-mail Notification
> - Editable Email Notification
> - Set build status on GitHub commit [deprecated]
> - Set status for GitHub commit [universal]
> - Trigger parameterized build on other projects
> - Delete workspace when build is done

What am I missing?

---

Basically I need this to destroy my VM instance in case of provisioning error (e.g. `vagrant destroy -f`).

I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.7.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins)

Comment: I see it's not listed in your list, but for me, _Post build task_  shows up in a fresh install. I've added it as an answer, as it's a bit hard to illustrate in comments. (Jenkins 2.7.1 with postbuild-task 1.8)

Comment: Did you restart Jenkins after plugin installation? After I remove the plugin (and restart Jenkins) this option is gone, so it really comes from that plugin.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I think the plugin was called _Hudson Post build task_, so I was confused that I've it already, but I didn't. I thought by having _post-build action_ that means that I have this plugin.

Comment: I think this question can be actually closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the *Add post-build action* button and select *Post build task*, which is provided by the mentioned [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin:

[image]

Afterwards, you have Tasks, each with an input field *Script*, where you can execute your commands:

[image]