# Jenkins run a shell command when build is failed as a post build action to run failed TestNG plan

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to rerun, below shell script in  the same project, once my build is i completed with errors, so I can rerun my failed test cases in testng-failed.xml.

```
FILE=./target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
mvn clean test -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy-dev.aws.skynet.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dproxy-dev.aws.skynet.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dbrowser="${Browser}" -Dbrowser_version="${browser_version}" -Dos_version="10" -Dos="Windows" -Dlocalrun="false"  -Dtestxml=FILE
else
   echo "$FILE is not there"
fi
```

But in Jenkins, post build section, I don't see an option to add Execute shell. Please help.

[image: Post build plugin is available in maven]

[image]

I installed post build plugin , but  it's only show for maven projects and not for my free style project.

In free style project, No post steps option.
[image: No post step option in freestyle project]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute Shell Script after post build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160363/execute-shell-script-after-post-build-in-jenkins)

Comment: Is there are any straight forward way of doing it ? I'm using a shared Jenkins server with other teams so adding a plugin  need an internal approval.

Comment: Nope. You need that plugin to enable that functionality when using freestyle jobs.
You can use a pipeline job instead which will enable this logic out of the box.

Comment: it's not usable  in free style project , seems it's only for maven projects as I only see Post steps options in the Maven project only.

Comment: What do you mean not usable? we are using it it in many freestyle jobs. If you cant use it just extract the post build logic to a separate job and call it from the post build of the original job - that way you will have full control.

Comment: Yes , it seems weird may be a version issue , did not see a post steps option in free style project but found that in maven project. Anyway, thanks a lot for your kind support. I did found a walkaround for this . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a walkaround to do this without any plugins and still run in the Jenkins free style project. Add two execute shells and in first shell enter the below shell commands.

```
export M2_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
mvn --version
cd CommonPagesStorage
mvn clean install -DskipTests
cd ..
cd MultiWebdriverDemo
mvn clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=TestSuites/${TestPlanName} 
echo "${TestPlanName}is ran"

#Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true added this so even the script failed it doesn't mark as fail and mark it as unstable and continue.
```

In the second shell command ,conditionally checks the testng-failed.xml is exists if so run it to run the failed test cases.

```
cd MultiWebdriverDemo
export M2_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
mvn --version

#this to print current directory.
echo "the second Script executed from: ${PWD}"

if [ -e ./target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml ]
then
    echo "ok file found pass"
    mvn  test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml
else
    echo "file not found passed in first attempt ..."
    exit 0
    #exit 0 means forcefully mark it as passed

fi

if [ -e ./target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml ]
then
    echo "Rerun also failed exiting with buil state as failure "
    exit 1
 #exit 1 means forcefully mark it as failed
else
    echo "file not found rerun is passed marking the build as passed ..."
     exit 0
fi
```

[image]

S0 even in the second time, my webdriver test case is failed, it's failed build mark as a failure.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.199 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-12T14:05:36Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ [ -e ./target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml ]
+ echo Rerun also failed exiting with buil state as failure 
Rerun also failed exiting with buil state as failure 
+ exit 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Saving reports...
Processing '/var/jenkins_home/jobs/August-FreeStyle/builds/37/testng/testng-results.xml'
100.000000% of tests failed, which exceeded threshold of 0%. Marking build as UNSTABLE
TestNG Reports Processing: FINISH
Finished: FAILURE
```